# Internet Connection Sharing, can't Share Wireless

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection, ad-hoc-network

I'm using Windows XP, and I've been trying to setup my laptop so that I can connect to the internet connection that I get on the laptop through my mobile on an ad-hoc network. I've set up an ad-hoc network, but when I try to select "allow other users to connect through this computers internet connection", the only options I have are the Local Area Connections.

[image: The dialog I get]

The tutorial I've been using says that Wireless Connection should be in that pull down menu. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, if you just want to connect from `laptop -> phone -> internet`, you do NOT want 'Internet Connection Sharing'. ICS is for the case where you want to do something like:

```
desktop -> laptop -> phone -> internet
       or
laptop -> desktop -> DSL internet
```

If you just want to connect your laptop through your phone, we'll need to know what phone you have, and what you set up on your phone to enable this feature (it varies for different phones).

Comment: No, I'm wanting to broadcast the internet connection I get from my laptop as a wifi hotspot so that my phone can connect to it.

Comment: Does your phone support ad-hoc wireless connections? many of them do not

Comment: Yeah, I'm running Android with modified files. I'm pretty sure the phone is set up correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP doesn't have this feature as far as I know, but [connectify.me](http://connectify.me) is an app for Windows 7 that shares/tethers your internet connection as a wifi hotspot.